# Why is b4 the only move suggested by every chess engine?

Tags: analysis, tactics, evaluation

The only move suggested here by every chess engine is `17. b4`

Can anyone please advise why is it so important?

```
[fen "r3k2r/ppp2pp1/7p/3pP3/3P2b1/5N2/RP1KBPPP/7R w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: A way for you to figure this out is to play other moves and see how the engine punishes you.

Comment: I tried many moves and trust there are many moves that yield good score. But this move yields a way too high score compared to other. And I was wondering why. But then @Tanj 's answer did help a lot

Comment: How do you embed this fantastic game player into the post? I've been having difficulty finding documentation on it.

Comment: @Nebri I don't know if the documentation is in one place, but some information is on meta.  http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post

Another way is to 'view source' on one of our web pages with a board and see how it is done.  It's fiddly but not too hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Black is down material but still has some strength. The most obvious one is that he has a pawn majority on the queenside, meaning potentially passed pawn if he manages to push his majority. So Black's plan will be to put both rooks behind the pawns and go for ...a5-a4, ...b5-b4 etc...

In a very simple way White can fight against Black play (it's prophylaxie) by pushing b4 preventing ...a5 and ...c5.
Moreover if we manage to push b4-b5, the pawn on a7 will now be a weakness so we can attack it (doubling rooks on a-file).

Comment: awesome! yes, occupying b4 kind of troubles black pawn advances. Plus white's rooks are easy to occupy the open files. The only strength in black's play is queenside pawns, so true. Thank you @Tanj